# TCPDF setPageRegions and multicell

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm trying to add a no-text region on the first three lines of my multicell text. The problem is that it will align all text based on where the first row is and the 4th line will not wrap in under the no-text region. If i move down the no-text region below the first row of text then it wrapping the text around the no-text region.

```
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
$img_width = 5;
$img_height = 10;
$text = 'alot of text';
$regions = array(
    array(
        'page' => '',
        'xt' => $x + $img_width,
        'yt' => $y,
        'xb' => $x + $img_width,
        'yb' => $y + $img_height,
        'side' => 'L'
    )
);
$this->setPageRegions($regions);
$this->MultiCell($text...$x,$y...);
```

Expected result

```
     row 1 ....
     row 2 ....
     row 3 ....
row 4 ....
row 5 ....
row 6 ....
```

Actual result

```
     row 1 ....
     row 2 ....
     row 3 ....
     row 4 ....
     row 5 ....
     row 6 ....
```

Result if no-text region is moved down one row

```
row 1 ....
     row 2 ....
     row 3 ....
     row 4 ....
row 5 ....
row 6 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is already 2 years old I stumbled over the same issue.

The pageRegions on the left side do not work as expected, when the y value of the page region is the same y value as the beginning of the text section.

The solution (tested with a left-to-right text; right-to-left might need some more adjustment) is a "fix" of checkPageRegions function in tcpdf.php.

Add a "else" part to the region boundaries check starting at line 22630 with

```
if (($y >= ($regdata['yt'] - $h)) AND ($y <= $regdata['yb'])) {

...

} else {
    if ($this->rtl) {
        $x = min($this->clMargin, $this->original_lMargin);
    } else {
        $x = min($this->crMargin, $this->original_rMargin);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps others looking for a solution.